# How can I override 'base_edit' view for a type using portal_factory?

Tags: plone

It seems that when I use the `portal_factory` tool for creating an instance of a type it disregards the view I've specified to override `base_edit`.

Here's what I've got setup:

1. Alias from `edit` to `base_edit` in the types tool.
2. View class that renders the view.
3. ZCML that that hooks on the view class to the appropriate interface.
4. Content class that implements the appropriate interface.

I know my overridden `base_edit` view works because it renders:

1. Once the object has been created it renders.
2. When I disable the `portal_factory` tool for the type.

When I use another name like `custom_edit` it also renders the overridden view, despite the type being enabled in the `portal_factory` tool.

Comment: That makes no sense; `portal_factory` does not change what edit view is being used.

Comment: Explained a little more and added a temporary workaround.

Comment: Try @@base_edit as alias from edit. Did you also set the "immediate_view" property?

Comment: @mat - That worked a treat. Can you perhaps put that in an answer and explain why it works? Didn't have to do anything with the "immediate_view" property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the alias to @@base_edit works too. 
this way zope traversing makes an adapter lookup instead of attribute access and your edit view will be used.

afaik the @@ forces an adapter lookup, without @@ the first object thru acquisition is called and then an adapter

cc @juriejan

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to customized the `base_edit.cpt`, you simply need to create a new CMF skin template called `yourtypenamenormalized_edit.pt`, where "yourtypenamenormalized" is your portal_type name lowercase and without spaces.
The original Archetype base_edit.cpt [will look for a template called this way](https://github.com/plone/Products.Archetypes/blob/624508fd943fd8d1019558a19e3f3ee2ece3eb51/Products/Archetypes/skins/archetypes/base_edit.cpt#L20) before applying all default macros.

After that I suggest you to fill this new template with all the code you'll find inside the default template, that is [edit_macro.pt](https://github.com/plone/Products.Archetypes/blob/450c526102d038e0cf51c27d8841404905cc86ea/Products/Archetypes/skins/archetypes/edit_macros.pt), then start to apply your changes.

Commonly the only macro you'll want to override is the **body** macro.

Comment: Would there be a way to hook up a view class for this solution? I also realized that I could use this route, but I'm separating my view logic into a view class, and using templates only for display logic. IF that makes any sense.